# Splitting data in one column and updating new column with split data

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm working on Oracle 10g.One of the column's of my table stores data, as sampled below.

```
1722999340KK000200000

1444210829AB1001EX003

1444300000CD0148EX003

1722999340KL000200000
```

I want to split the data in the ratio of digits ( 4 ; 6; 6; 5) as shown below and store it in different columns

```
( A1 ||   A2   ||   A  3 || A4 )

1444 || 210829 || AB1001 || EX003
```

Appreciate if someone can give me some pointers on how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert when it comes to Oracle, but let's give it a shot. Assuming the original column is called ORIG, and the original data is some string type:

```
update <tablename> set A1 = substr(ORIG, 0, 4),
                       A2 = substr(ORIG, 4, 6),
                       A3 = substr(ORIG, 10, 6),
                       A4 = substr(ORIG, 16, 5);
```

Hope this helps

Tom

Comment: The substr function is definitely the simplest way to implement.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Almost right. Small changes had to be made to the digit positions. 
update temptab set C1 = substr(tempcol, 0, 4),
                       C2 = substr(tempcol, 4, 6),
                       C3 = substr(tempcol, 10, 6),
                       C4 = substr(tempcol, 16, 5);

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry. Typo error. The actual query is :
update temptab set C1 = substr(tempcol, 1, 4), C2 = substr(tempcol, 5, 6), C3 = substr(tempcol, 11, 6), C4 = substr(tempcol, 17);

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I wasn't too sure about that in the first place, anyway. Thanks for getting back to me.